# No device Found error with Cheese in Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: 20.04, webcam, cheese

I have been struggling to start my webcam as i need to clear an interview with a video conferencing. I updated the OS from 18.04 to 20.04 but still I get the message **No device found** when I try to open cheese. Below is the output of the command lsusb

```
nik@nik:/$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Below are some commands executed

```
   nik@nik:/$ sudo modprobe uvcvideo
   nik@nik:/$ 

   niket@nik:/$ sudo modprobe vfe_v4l2
   modprobe: FATAL: Module vfe_v4l2 not found in directory 
    /lib/modules/5.4.0-81-generic
   niket@nik:/$ sudo modprobe gc2035
    modprobe: FATAL: Module gc2035 not found in directory / 
     lib/modules/5.4.0-81-generic
```

Can someone clarify me if webcam drivers are not there or how do I need to resolve this problem. I have looked into lot of online docs and applied them but still cannot resolve this issue.

Comment: It would be nice to know the camera and model if you're plugging in a USB webcam, or if it's a built-in webcam. That would help, too.

Comment: I'd recommend  looking for the text  _uvcvideo_ in the output of dmesg, especially lines before and after it to get clues as to whether it was recognized, what devices it may have connected (or tried connecting) to and comparing that with the Preference / Webcam tab inside *cheese*

Comment: @mondotofu: its a inbuilt cam

Comment: dmseg returns nothing, niket@nik:~$ dmesg | grep -i "uvcvideo"

Answer (score 0):

try updating grub:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="

https://jrexplorer.blogspot.com/2017/03/cheese-no-device-found-in-ubuntu-1404.html